# Uploading Spock/Groovy test results into Sonarqube

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

There was a known issue from 2014 that UnitTests written in Groovy cannot have their PASS/FAIL metrics uploaded into SonarQube.

http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Resource-not-found-for-Groovy-unit-tests-td5024669.html

Does anyone know if this issue is fixed?  I am still have the issue with Sonar 6.1 using Spock unit tests and Gradle build system.

Any clue on the correct gradle sonar settings to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for us was to install the Groovy plugin in Sonarqube 6.1.

Once the plugin was installed, we could see the tests, with this command line:

```
./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.tests=src/test/groovy -Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test-results/test/
```

We are using Spock as well (with Gradle, as you can see)